# addRule isn't worfking for TableLayout

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use .addRule for my TableLayout to be in the center of the RelativeLayout but it doesn't do anything at all.
Here is my code:

```
RelativeLayout RL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.play_RL);
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
```

In between I create my tableLayout containing 2 rows and 2 columns with 4 buttons total
then I try to add the table on the RL RelativeLayout

```
RL.addView(tableLayout);
```

but its shows on the top left corner not in the centre as I expected

Comment: Call the `addView()` method with `relativeLayoutParams` as the second argument.

Comment: unfortunately again nothing happened

Comment: Oh, yeah, you want `WRAP_CONTENT` instead of `MATCH_PARENT` for the width and height, too.

Comment: oh yeah you are absolutely correct. Thank you very much!!!!